# HTML5 Links on menubar leaves current page

Tags: css, html

I have a menu bar that links to local webpages that is working fine except that when I click on the link on the menubar it goes to the webpage in question leaving the webpage with the menubar, but I wish to load the page below the menubar so the user can this use the menubar to navigate. Should I be using iframes? sorry haven't used HMTL5 in quite some time any help is much appreciated.

Neil.

```
<div class="menu">
        <a href="home.hmtl">Home</a>
        <a href="index.html">Index of Services</a>
        <a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a>
        <a href="examples.hmtl">Examples</a>
     </div>
    <div class="content">

    This page is to help you organise

</div>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, you need frames. Or, the most common, to have the same menu code on all htmls, because with frames your url won't change unless you do some tricks.

If you don't want to duplicate code you could use PHP. Then you could create an index.php with the menus and with includes to the page content.

Edit:
You can also do it with some JavaScript but it also has the same problems with the url. The site will also not work if JavaScript is disabled.

Edit2:
The tricks for frames and javascript I said before can be achieved without url rewrites and with plain HTML+CSS+JS is with anchors.

Basically you change your urls to anchors with the page name, and when the page is first loaded you check this hash so the correct frame opens when someone enters your url like `http://mypage.com/#examples`. You can access and set the hash with `window.location.hash`.

So your code would look like:

```
<div class="menu">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#index">Index of Services</a>
    <a href="#schedule">Schedule</a>
    <a href="#examples">Examples</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
    This page is to help you organise
</div>
```

For both with or without frames you need a JavaScript event attached to each menu item.

With frames the JS basically changes the frame url when the user clicks on the menu.

Without frames you use `xhr` to download the html, and then, if you successfully downloaded the html, you delete everything inside `div.content` and replace with what you downloaded with `innerHtml`.

For both solutions you need to add a JS that checks the hash when you first load the page to update the displayed page accordingly.

As for PHP or other server-sided "script" any beginners tutorial will explain how to do it.

Comment: By the way, there are alternatives to PHP, like NodeJS or Python for example.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help it's much appreciated

Comment: @Batmandub I'm glad it helped. I edited my answer now that I had more time to point to what tricks you can use. And you may set my answer as the accepted answer if it did.